# Admob unable to display in iOS 6 device

Tags: objective-c, ios6, admob

```
- (UIView *)addbanner{
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0, 0);
self.adBanner = [[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:origin]autorelease];
headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320, self.adBanner.adSize.size.height)] autorelease];
self.adBanner.adUnitID = @"a14fe853330ee80";
self.adBanner.delegate = self;
[self.adBanner setRootViewController:self];
[headerView addSubview:self.adBanner];
[self.adBanner loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
return headerView;
}

- (GADRequest *)createRequest {
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testing = NO;
return request;
}

- (void)bannerView:(GADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"error %@", error);
}

- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView
{
NSLog(@"success");
}
```

When I tried on iOS 5 device in both developer and distribution mode also can display.

When I tried on iOS 6 device in both developer and distribution mode but unable to display.

[Here](https://itunes.apple.com/app/oriental-daily-news/id570920708?mt=8) is my apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to get test ads on iOS 6 as that doesn't work right now (link to the [forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/test%2420ios%24206/google-admob-ads-sdk/WaW00YBVL6I/fYpukjJBPSoJ)).

However if you're not receiving ads on iOS 6 right away it just sounds like an issue of fill (not having the inventory) which should straighten itself out as time goes on. If you want to test tat your ad flow is correct you can create a house ad campaign fully allocated to a test publisher ID, and use the test publisher ID into your applications to test.